# Single line with Dash stroke style with PyQGIS implementation

Tags: pyqgis, symbology, style, qgsvectorlayer

I have a simple vector layer with **LineString** geometry. I want to styling this with **dash line**. How can I implement this with PyQGIS? I need to implement **Stroke style** property and **red color** as styling.

[image]

Comment: How about saving the style in qml format (xml) and applying it to a layer?

Answer (score 1):

```
symbol = QgsLineSymbol.createSimple({'line_style':'dash','color':symbolColor, 'width':'1.5'})
layer.renderer().setSymbol(symbol)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: It working fine.